# tbl_uvregression for lme4 objects

Tags: lme4, gtsummary

I am trying to get a univariate regression table using tbl_uvregression from gtsummary. I am running these regression models with lme4 and I am not sure where and how to specify the random effect. Here's an example using the trial data from the survival package.

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)

data(trial)


trial %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = glmer,
    y = response,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2),
  formula = "{y} ~ {x}+ {1|grade}"
  )
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `formula_chr`.
#> x object 'grade' not found
#> i Input `formula_chr` is `glue(formula)`.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Please help

Comment: can you change your formula line to this  : `formula = "{y} ~ {x}+ (1|grade)"`

Answer (score 3):

For the RE in the model do not specify with the `{}` instead use `()`.

```
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)

data(trial)


trial %>%
    tbl_uvregression(
        method = glmer,
        y = response,
        method.args = list(family = binomial),
        exponentiate = TRUE,
        pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2),
        formula = "{y} ~ {x}+ (1|grade)"
    )
```